# Given that the earth Dracula sleeps on must have been consecrated, why does holy water ruin it?

Tags: horror, dracula, bram-stoker

It seems that Dracula’s dirt-bed must be consecrated (and originate from his native Transylvania), or to be “holy dirt,” so how can the addition of holy water make it utterly useless to the Count as a resting/rejuvenating spot?

Comment: What makes you think that the soil is consecrated? That would make no sense as Vampires are unholy.

Comment: The dirt he ships to England comes from what appears to be a burial ground inside a church (this would almost guaranteee that it would have been consecrated,) A cursory online search also provides similar results, For  instance, here is the top pick from a google search - Martina Slechtova, from Quora, states: “Boxes of earth are boxes full of consecrated dirt in which Dracula can regenerate his powers. It is a special Transsylvanian dirt which is somehow connected to his homeland.”

Comment: Hmm.. I doubt that adding holy water to consecrated earth would make that much difference, where does this question originate?

Comment: This question originates from the narrative of Stoker’s ‘Dracula.’ In this story holy water seems to be the best way to ruin the Count’s earth/dirt he had brought over from Transylvania.

Comment: I can't find anything useful I'm afraid. It doesn't feel consistent.

Comment: You're assuming the dirt is still "consecrated" after it's been dug up. Digging up a graveyard is generally considered desecration.

Comment: In my opinion, this only seems to push the problem one step back as now we have the question “why does Dracula need to sleep in unconsecrated earth that had once been consecrated?” Otherwise why would Stoker go to the trouble of letting us know from exactly where in Transylvania the earth Dracula shipped originated?

Answer (score 8):

Here are Van Helsing's words as he produces [the consecrated host](https://www.dummies.com/religion/christianity/catholicism/consecrated-host-catholicism/) which he will use to render the boxes of soil uninhabitable for Dracula:

> "And now, my friends, we have a duty here to do. **We must sterilize this earth**, so sacred of holy memories, that he has brought from a far distant land for such fell use. He has chosen this earth because it has been holy. Thus we defeat him with his own weapon, for **we make it more holy still. It was sanctified to such use of man, now we sanctify it to God.**"

The soil is chosen for multiple purposes: it must be from the vampire's home country because they need a connection to their "home ground" (this is an invention from Stoker), and because that earth is drenched in all the blood that has been spilled on it throughout history.

Moreover, since it is (apparently) earth from a graveyard -- look at the phrase "because it has been holy" in the above quote -- this soil is the result of a [desecration](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/desecration).

---

Stoker's Dracula is a representation of evil; in that context the opposite of that is represented by religious items like a crucifix or holy water, and such items can hold sway over vampires.

According to the book ***The Everything Vampire Book: From Vlad the Impaler to the vampire Lestat -- a history of vampires in Literature, Film, and Legend*** by Barbara Karg, Rick Sutherland, Arjean Spaite:

> Stoker's use of the Eucharist speaks to a range of issues, including good versus evil, moral versus immoral, and dark versus light. No doubt the religious significance of the wafer is **a religious reinforcement to the spiritual turmoil of the Victorian era**. One possible reason that the wafers aren't as popularly used as holy water is likely due to accessibility. As **a powerful representation of the body of Christ**, wafers are typically locked away in tabernacles within churches and chapels and not easily acquired.

Comment: Basically, Drakula is twisting the power of God by desecrating the holy, consecrated ground. Because it was once holy, it held a power of God in some way. Using that power for your own purposes is Drakula's goal. I think of it as difference between adding a teaspoon of salt into your soup and adding a whole pound of it. One improves the taste, the other ruins it.